# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и" в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом *и* в следующем предложении?

*То, чем я занимаюсь и где нахожусь, мне очень нравится.*

Answer (score 3):

Это однородные придаточные, запятая не нужна.